# What is the headlights bulb size for Daewoo Lanos?

Tags: headlight, bulbs, daewoo

I'm totally new to cars. I've been trying to figure out the appropriate size for my Daewoo Lanos headlight bulbs (H4, H7 , ...etc). However, I couldn't find it any where in the manual, and Google search wasn't conclusive. How can I find the right size?

Comment: I would take the bulb out and the shape will tell you.

Comment: The manual should say, or you could go to a website such as https://www.halfords.com/motoring/bulbs/ which will tell you all the bulbs for your car

Comment: Rory, isn’t your comment actually an solid answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as Solar Mark suggested and tried to replace it with an H4 bulp. It was a perfect fit.